# Instragram's UUID Creation Failing in PostgreSQL 9.3.5 with the error "operator does not exist: bigint %% integer"

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, uuid, sharding

I'm trying to implement Instagram's UUID that they talked about in this post: http://instagram-engineering.tumblr.com/post/10853187575/sharding-ids-at-instagram

> But I keep getting this error: **operator does not exist: bigint %% integer**

My implementation looks like this:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE table_id_seq;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION next_id(OUT result bigint) AS $$
DECLARE
    our_epoch bigint := 1314220021721;
    seq_id bigint;
    now_millis bigint;
    shard_id int := 5;
BEGIN
    SELECT nextval('table_id_seq') %% 1024 INTO seq_id;
    SELECT FLOOR(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM clock_timestamp()) * 1000) INTO now_millis;
    result := (now_millis - our_epoch) << 23;
    result := result | (shard_id << 10);
    result := result | (seq_id);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;

CREATE TABLE items
(
   id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT next_id(),
   path character(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''::bpchar,
   CONSTRAINT items_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
--##check the table
instagram=# \d items
                 Table "public.items"
 Column |      Type      |          Modifiers
--------+----------------+-----------------------------
 id     | bigint         | not null default next_id()
 path   | character(255) | not null default ''::bpchar
Indexes:
    "items_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

my environments:

```
PostgreSQL 9.3.5 on x86_64-apple-darwin13.2.0, compiled by Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn), 64-bit
```

I keep getting this error:

```
INSERT INTO items ("path") VALUES('/var/images/xxx.jpg');

ERROR:  operator does not exist: bigint %% integer
LINE 1: SELECT nextval('table_id_seq') %% 1024
                                   ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
QUERY:  SELECT nextval('table_id_seq') %% 1024
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function next_id() line 8 at SQL statement
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
SELECT nextval('table_id_seq') %% 1024 INTO seq_id;
```

should become:

```
SELECT nextval('table_id_seq') % 1024 INTO seq_id;
```